# jtable takes "" into database when editing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, null-pointer

here is my sample code

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
   int colum=jTable1.getSelectedColumn();
   int row=jTable1.getSelectedRow();
   System.out.println("row of selected is "+row+"col is "+colum);
    String remark1 = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 8);
    String remark2 = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 9);
     String stock = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 10);
     String invoiceno =(String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 11);            
    String id=(String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 12);
    System.out.println("remark1: "+remark1+" ,remark2: "+remark2+",stock:"+stock+", invoiceno:"+invoiceno+ " ,id: "+id);
```

when ever I open the `jTable1` in edit mode and come out without entering text into it and perform the action ill get output like this

```
remark1:  ,remark2: ,stock: , invoiceno: ,id: 7e3c63ffc9bc42dba8155270741d7c9a
```

and when i send that row to database at that fields its taking `"` at those fields.. which is creating me problem. how do i stop by not sending `"` into database when I just go into edit mode and come out of it without editing text/adding text

I tried adding this

```
line 426: if(invoiceno.equals("")){
         invoiceno=null;
     }
```

if i go into editmode of `invoiceno` `jTable1` and come out, its passing argument `invoiceno=null` and working fine.
But if I dont go into that row(editmode) then send into database then its showing null `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `line:426`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: umm yea i tried for it.. but i have a lot of code in it there :( its just take `"` into database even if i go into edit mode and dont enter text in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reverse your validation, doing

```
if ("".equals(invoiceno)) {
  invoiceno = null;
}
```

instead which would not throw a `NullPointerException` if `invoiceno` is `null`.